# How to set DNS in Ubuntu so that it wouldnt interfere with a VPN connection?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I have started using a VPN service and I only have a live internet connection when the VPN service is set to "connected". The moment I turn it off....I lose the internet connection.

I was advised to set my DNS to " 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4". I have never done this and I don't excel at networking.

I have looked at this link and the information it contains (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html), but I am not pro enough to do it without someone walking me through the steps.

How do I set fixed DNS values in Ubuntu 16.04? Ideally using a graphical way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have set up your vpn settings graphically via the network manager.
Whilst setting up a vpn connection, you have a tab on the side named ipv4. If you click on that you get a form where you can set the DNS adress that you want to use. I have not tested this out, but by my understanding it should work.

Edit:
When you set up a VPN connection, it should look like something like this:
[Set DNS address for VPN connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMwj4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at the top left hand side of your screen next to the date and volume and what not there is an icon with two arrows click on that.

1. Then click on edit connections..
2. Then ensure Ethernet is highlighted,
   on the left click on add.
3. add a new network with standard settings not the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
   this way when you are not on the vpn you can click on the arrow icon and select this network.

I presume this would work.